# Missing { inserted. \bar when writing an equation

Tags: equations, errors

I would like to write the following equation:

[image]

For that, I have the following snippet:

```
    \begin{equation}
    s_i = \left\{\begin{matrix}
    \bar{1}, & \text{if } x < -\epsilon \\ 
    0, & \text{if } \left | x \right | \leq \epsilon \\ 
    1, & \text{if } x > \epsilon \
    \end{matrix}\right.
    \end{equation}
```

I get the following error when I compile:

```
Missing { inserted. \bar
Missing } inserted. \bar
Undefined control sequence. \bar{1}, \& \text
Misplaced alignment tab character &. 0, &
Undefined control sequence. 0, & \text
Misplaced alignment tab character &. 1, &
Undefined control sequence. 1, & \text
```

Can someone help me with solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no error message when I complete the code. However, the ‘if’ in the third tow is not well aligned with the first two, for a reason I can't explain. This problem disappears using the `cases` environment, which furthermore  has a simpler code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
s_i = \begin{cases}
\bar{1}, & \text{if } x < -\epsilon \\
0, & \text{if\,} \left | x \right | \leq \epsilon \\
1, & \text{if } x > \epsilon \
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That solved the issue. Basically, I just added the package `\usepackage{mathtools}`.

Comment: The `cases` is not defined by mathtools, but by `amsmath`(which is anyway loaded by mathtools, since it is a (very useful) extension of amsmath).

Comment: The reason the "if" in the third row is not aligned when `matrix` is used is that the columns are all defined to be centered for `matrix` and that element happens to be shorter than the others.

Comment: Oh! yes, of course. I had in mind it was a plain `array` environment, and mainly wondered why the O.P. didn't use cases. Thank you!